# Transaction issue with Castle.Facilities.AutoTx error "Illegal attempt to associate a collection with two open sessions"

Tags: nhibernate, transactions, castle-windsor

We are using in a project some Castle facilities, to be specific Castle Automatic transactions and NHibernateIntegration facilities.

The initial setup was transactions per method,but we had a problem with rollback a entire unit of work. All was working fine. Our Castle configuration for these small transaction per method is:

```
<component id="SessionModule"
             service="BCS.Modules.ISessionModule, BCS.Modules"
             type="BCS.Modules.SessionModule, BCS.Impl"
             isTransactional="true">     
     <transaction>
        <method name="GetCurrentDate" />
        <method name="GetCurrentDateAndTime" />
     </transaction>
  </component>
```

Then we start having problems with rollback operations in a entire request, so we decide to group in a father transaction all the unitary transactions per business transaction by example:

```
namespace BCS.BusinessRules {
   [Transactional]
   public class TransactionModule : ITransactionModule {

      [Transaction( TransactionMode.Requires, IsolationMode.ReadUncommitted, Distributed = false )]
      public Dictionary<String, double> CalculateGoalSetting( Member member, WorkflowContext contextSetting ) { 
       // Calling a lot of child transactional methods for this unit of work
      }

      [Transaction( TransactionMode.Requires, IsolationMode.ReadUncommitted, Distributed = false )]
      public MembershipOperationResult SelfEnrollment( Member member ) {
          // Same here, Another unit of work      
      }

   }

}
```

These unit of work are called one per request in our web application. But after that we start having problems like **Illegal attempt to associate a collection with two open sessions**, **Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.** and some times **dead-locks**

The most frequent error is one:

Server Error in '/' Application.
Illegal attempt to associate a collection with two open sessions 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: NHibernate.HibernateException: Illegal attempt to associate a collection with two open sessions

Source Error: 
An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

```
[HibernateException: Illegal attempt to associate a collection with two open sessions]
   NHibernate.Collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.SetCurrentSession(ISessionImplementor session) +242
   NHibernate.Event.Default.OnUpdateVisitor.ProcessCollection(Object collection, CollectionType type) +177
   NHibernate.Event.Default.AbstractVisitor.ProcessEntityPropertyValues(Object[] values, IType[] types) +83
   NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.PerformUpdate(SaveOrUpdateEvent event, Object entity, IEntityPersister persister) +632
   NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.PerformSaveOrUpdate(SaveOrUpdateEvent event) +101
   NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.OnSaveOrUpdate(SaveOrUpdateEvent event) +365
   NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.FireSaveOrUpdate(SaveOrUpdateEvent event) +394
   NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.SaveOrUpdate(String entityName, Object obj) +392
   NHibernate.Engine.Cascade.CascadeOn(IEntityPersister persister, Object parent, Object anything) +578
   NHibernate.Event.Default.AbstractFlushingEventListener.CascadeOnFlush(IEventSource session, IEntityPersister persister, Object key, Object anything) +157
   NHibernate.Event.Default.AbstractFlushingEventListener.PrepareEntityFlushes(IEventSource session) +364
   NHibernate.Event.Default.AbstractFlushingEventListener.FlushEverythingToExecutions(FlushEvent event) +225
   NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultAutoFlushEventListener.OnAutoFlush(AutoFlushEvent event) +83
   NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.AutoFlushIfRequired(ISet`1 querySpaces) +474
   NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.List(CriteriaImpl criteria, IList results) +782
   NHibernate.Impl.CriteriaImpl.List(IList results) +63
   NHibernate.Impl.CriteriaImpl.UniqueResult() +69
   BCS.Modules.Behavior.BehaviorElementDataAccess.GetByName(String name) in c:\Projects\dps\bcs\branches\bcs31\BCS.Impl\Modules\Behavior\BehaviorElementDataAccess.cs:41
   BCS.Modules.Behavior.BehaviorManagerModule.FindBehaviorElementByName(String behaviorName) in c:\Projects\dps\bcs\branches\bcs31\BCS.Impl\Modules\Behavior\BehaviorManagerModule.cs:191
   Castle.Proxies.Invocations.IBehaviorManagerModule_FindBehaviorElementByName.InvokeMethodOnTarget() +147
   Castle.DynamicProxy.AbstractInvocation.Proceed() in e:\OSS.Code\Castle.Core\src\Castle.Core\DynamicProxy\AbstractInvocation.cs:144
   Castle.Facilities.AutoTx.TransactionInterceptor.Intercept(IInvocation invocation) in c:\dev\dotnet\castle\main\Castle.Facilities.AutomaticTransactionManagement\src\Castle.Facilities.AutoTx\TransactionInterceptor.cs:92
   Castle.DynamicProxy.AbstractInvocation.Proceed() in e:\OSS.Code\Castle.Core\src\Castle.Core\DynamicProxy\AbstractInvocation.cs:166
   Castle.Proxies.IBehaviorManagerModuleProxy.FindBehaviorElementByName(String behaviorName) +356
   KAO.Behavior.CommonBehaviorCalculations.SaveGoalActivityMinutes(Member member, JulianDate startingDate, JulianDate endingDate, JulianDate currentDate) in c:\svn\qupio21\KAO\Behavior\CommonBehaviorCalculations.cs:148
   KAO.BusinessRules.TransactionModule.CalculateGoalSetting(Member member, WorkflowContext contextSetting) in c:\svn\qupio21\KAO.BusinessRules\TransactionModule.cs:111
   Castle.Proxies.Invocations.ITransactionModule_CalculateGoalSetting.InvokeMethodOnTarget() +155
   Castle.DynamicProxy.AbstractInvocation.Proceed() in e:\OSS.Code\Castle.Core\src\Castle.Core\DynamicProxy\AbstractInvocation.cs:144
   Castle.Facilities.AutoTx.TransactionInterceptor.Intercept(IInvocation invocation) in c:\dev\dotnet\castle\main\Castle.Facilities.AutomaticTransactionManagement\src\Castle.Facilities.AutoTx\TransactionInterceptor.cs:169
   Castle.DynamicProxy.AbstractInvocation.Proceed() in e:\OSS.Code\Castle.Core\src\Castle.Core\DynamicProxy\AbstractInvocation.cs:166
   Castle.Proxies.ITransactionModuleProxy.CalculateGoalSetting(Member member, WorkflowContext context) +183
   BCS.Web.App.Landing.Tunneling.Goals.cmdCalculate_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\svn\qupio21\BCS.Web.App\Landing\Tunneling\Goals.aspx.cs:104
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +155
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +3707


Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.272
```

Our data access layer is using the NHibernate Integration facility, with the current opened session:

```
   public class BehaviorElementDataAccess : DataAccessBase<BehaviorElement, Int64>, IBehaviorElementDataAccess {

      public BehaviorElementDataAccess( ISessionManager sessionManager ) : base( sessionManager ) { }


      public T GetById<T>( long id ) where T : BehaviorElement {
         T ret;
         using ( ISession session = SessionManager.OpenSession( ) ) {
            ret = session.Load<T>( id );
            session.Evict( ret );
         }
         return ret;
      }
}
```

We don't know how two sessions are used here, before the child transactions all was working fine, now our concurrency was reduced significantly. 
My initial thoughts, the default value for the transaction with Castle AutoTX is IsolationLevel.ReadCommited for those in the XML that only was declared in the XML configuration file, in the other hand the transaction declared in the code file, are IsolationLevel.ReadUncommited, so the child's must inherit this behavior also share the same Hibernate  Session for the transactions.

Does the isolation level of the database at Nhibernate level affectthis one? We have this setting for the database in our facilities>:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<castle>
       <!-- Facilities -->
       <facilities>
          <facility id="atm" type="Castle.Facilities.AutoTx.TransactionFacility, Castle.Facilities.AutoTx">
          </facility>
          <facility id="nhibernate" type="Castle.Facilities.NHibernateIntegration.NHibernateFacility, Castle.Facilities.NHibernateIntegration">
             <factory id="nhibernate.factory" alias="nh.facility.default">
                <settings>
                   <item key="connection.provider">NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider</item>
                   <item key="connection.driver_class">NHibernate.Driver.SqlClientDriver</item>
                   <item key="connection.connection_string_name">SQLServerConnection</item>
                   <item key="connection.isolation">ReadCommitted</item>
                   <item key="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2008Dialect</item>
                   <item key="adonet.batch_size">0</item>
                   <item key="use_outer_join">true</item>
                   <item key="query.substitutions">true 1, false 0, yes 'Y', no 'N'</item>
                   <item key="show_sql">true</item>
                   <item key="command_timeout">600</item>
                   <item key="proxyfactory.factory_class">NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle.ProxyFactoryFactory, NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle</item>
                   <item key="cache.use_minimal_puts">true</item>
                </settings>
                <assemblies>
                   <assembly>BCS.Impl</assembly>
                </assemblies>
                <listeners>
                   <listener type="BCS.NHibernate.Types.ActivitySaveUpdateListener, BCS.Impl" event="Save"/>
                   <listener type="BCS.NHibernate.Types.ActivitySaveUpdateListener, BCS.Impl" event="Update"/>
                   <listener type="BCS.NHibernate.Types.ActivitySaveUpdateListener, BCS.Impl" event="SaveUpdate"/>
                   <listener type="BCS.NHibernate.Types.ActivityDeleteListener, BCS.Impl" event="Delete"/>
                </listeners>

             </factory>
          </facility>
       </facilities>

       <include uri="file://modules.cfg.xml" />

    </castle>
```

I need to mention that the unit of work roll-back works perfectly, but some users at the same time got the  **NHibernate.HibernateException: Illegal attempt to associate a collection with two open sessions** all in our units of work, in other hand the nested transaction with father all these problems. We change the pool of IIS to ASP.Net 4.0 Classic without luck too....

We tried different things, but nothing is working.
Our Castle binaries version is:

```
Castle.Facilities.AutoTx 2.5.1.0
Castle.Facilities.NHibernateIntegration 1.1.0.0
Castle.Services.Transaction 2.5.0.0 
Castle.Windsor 2.5.1.0
NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle 3.1.0.4000 
NHibernate  3.1.0.4000
ASP.Net 4.0
```

Some has a similar problem or got some similar in the past?

Answer (score 0):

In the BehaviorElementDataAccess.GetById method, you are evicting the entity that you load, which will obviously remove it from the session.  However you are not doing anything about any related entities (particularly any collections in this instance).

I suspect that what is happening is you are loading the entity, then NHibernate creates proxies for it's associated collections and these proxies keep a reference to the session, then when you evict the loaded entity, the proxies still have this reference, so when you try to save it again later in the same session, because the entity was evicted, NHibernate tries to re-attach the entity to the session, but in doing so it tries to re-attach the collection proxies which already have a reference to the session and this causes the error.

I'm not sure why you are evicting the entities in your GetById method - I would suggest not doing so, it's bypassing a lot of the functionality that NHibernate offers.

Comment: Good catch, evicting object from session in transaction gives us all trouble. Thanks =)